# urllib.read() result return null value

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urllib, web-applications

I'm trying to read & print the result from google's URL in GAE. When i run the first program, output was blank. then i have added a print statement before printing the url result and run it. Now i got the result.

Why the Program 1 doesn't give any output ?

Program 1

```
import urllib

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler): 
def get(self):              
    url = urllib.urlopen("http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=100EUR%3D%3FAUD")
    result = url.read()
    print result
```

Program 2

```
import urllib

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler): 
def get(self):
    # Print something before print urllib result
    print "Result -"       
    url = urllib.urlopen("http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=100EUR%3D%3FAUD")
    result = url.read()
    print result
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `print` from inside a WSGI application. Never, ever use `print` from inside a WSGI application.

What's happening is that your text is being output in the place where the webserver expects to see headers, so your output is not displayed as you expect.

Instead, you should use `self.response.out.write()` to send output to the user, and `logging.info` etc for debugging data.

Answer (score 0):

I met this issue before. But cannot find an exactly answer about it yet.
maybe the `cache mechanism` cause this issue, not sure.
You need do `flush output` to print the data:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()
```

or just do like the way you did:

```
print "*" * 10
print data
```

---

I think you'll like `logging` when you are debugging:

```
logging.debug('A debug message here')
```

or

```
logging.info('The result is: %s', yourResultData)
```